# Issues with displaying graph ltspice simulation of CB characteristics

Tags: transistors, bjt, ltspice, simulation

Sometimes when I simulate the CB or CE characteristics of a BJT, for the input and output characteristics I get a graph that is inverted (upside down) rather than looking the way it normally should. The currents are all marked negative instead of positive. Any reasons why it should appear like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at voltage across a resistor, or current through a resistor, LTSpice assumes a 'forward direction'.  This assumption may be backwards from how you are thinking about the circuit.

If you get a graph that is inverted from your perspective, rotate the resistor the other way in the schematic to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can either place a negative sign in front of the measurement:
[image]

Or rotate the resistor 180 degrees to swap the pins.